# Who gets info when Apigee Trace is used by multiple people concurrently?

Tags: apigee

if three people are using Trace at the same time, would a request appear on all three trace consoles or on one console that happened to be lucky enough to get get the reading?

When we are validating releases, the trace seems a bit "wonkie" and I'd like to understand what to expect in this case

Answer (score 1):

If three people are tracing at the same time, all three people will get the same requests.